# I am trying to run cucumber features but got proxy error

Tags: ruby, proxy, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

when I run My cucumber test, I keep getting errors due to the authentication of my cooperate proxy.

the steps I have follow are:

- Installed Ruby (had to set my ENV(var) to "setx HTTP_PROXY user:password@proxy.com:8080"
- Installed cucumber
- Installed water-webdriver
- Created my folders and files
- get authentication error

I have set the proxy with all setting (0, 1, 2, 4 and 5) but all fail.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: found some info and the suggestion was to do the below

    # Remove any proxy settings
    ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] = nil
    ENV['http_proxy'] = nil

    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    profile["network.proxy.type"] = 2
    profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :pac => 'http://proxy.com.au/proxy.pac'
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile

Answer (score 1):

found some info and the suggestion was to do the below
    # Remove any proxy settings 
    ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] = nil 
    ENV['http_proxy'] = nil 
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new 
    profile["network.proxy.type"] = 2 profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :pac => 'proxy.com.au/proxy.pac'; 
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile

Answer (score 0):

Setting `ENV['http_proxy']` to  `nil` in `hooks.rb` worked perfectly for me.

```
ENV['http_proxy'] = nil
```

Initially I used to get `HTTP request path is empty (ArgumentError)` and solved it by adding `ENV['no_proxy'] = "127.0.0.1"` to `hooks.rb`

But this proxy setting helped me resolve both the errors.

Thank you for your answer.

Cheers! :)